# Virtualenv specific pip config files

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I need to use different pip config files depending on which project I'm currently working on. Each project pulls from a separate pypi repo and needs its own block in my .pip/pip.conf file

```
[global]
    timeout = 60
    index-url = <my_custom_pypi_repo>
```

Is there a way to provide a pip.conf file on a virtualenv specific basis?

Ideally when I run

```
 workon env1
 pip install env1_package
```

It would only try and download from the env1 config file

And similar for env2
Ideally when I run

```
 workon env2
 pip install env2_package
```

I would like it to not request this package from the env1 pypi server.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Found this after I had posted the question:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#configuration-files

```
 ~/.pip/pip.conf
```

You will need to set:

```
 ~/.virtualenvs/env1/pip.conf
 ~/.virtualenvs/env2/pip.conf
```

It will still inherit from:

```
 ~/.pip/pip.conf
```

But will allow it to be overwritten for each environment.

Comment: Note that as @sql_knievel states, on Windows the file needs to be called `pip.ini` instead of `pip.conf`.

Answer (score 18):

Just to update the answer here with the latest from [the pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/?highlight=pip.ini#location):

> Inside a virtualenv:
>
> - On Unix and macOS the file is $VIRTUAL_ENV/pip.conf
> - On Windows the file is: %VIRTUAL_ENV%\pip.ini

The $VIRTUAL_ENV environment variable gets set once you've activated the particular virtual environment you're interested in.